# No elements are added to the ObservableCollection from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I created the ObservableCollection, which works with bindings, etc. Now I have a problem when I add an item to the collection, it is not visible

Tried most things but probably missing some obvious things.

Main class:

```
public class MainClass
{
    public MainClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    static MainClass instance = null;
    static readonly object padlock = new object();

    public static MainClass Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new MainClass();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Server> _myListOfServersObjects;
    public ObservableCollection<Server> ObservableServers
    {
        get
        {
            if (_myListOfServersObjects == null)
                ObservableServers = new ObservableCollection<Server>();

            return _myListOfServersObjects;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_myListOfServersObjects != value)
            {
                _myListOfServersObjects = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ObservableServers");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add an item:

```
public class AnotherClass
{
    public void AddItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainClass.Instance.ObservableServers.Add(new Server("127.0.0.1:8890", "127.0.0.1:8890", false, "Test add", "23 / 1000", 82, "Test mode", "Test map"));
    }
}
```

WPF Main Class: https://pastebin.com/YzvdmhvW

WPF AnotherClass: https://pastebin.com/1pvT3Z35

Structure: https://pastebin.com/hqcwxcJz

Question relevant!!!

Comment: this example is not complete or reproducable ( [mcve] ). where and how AddItem is called? and how collection is displayed - maybe it is just incorrect bidning in a view

Comment: @ASh added more code.. thank you for your help in filling the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've defined the observable collection has some issues:

First of all, a `UIElement` (such as your MainClass) is a `DependencyObject` and does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Therefore calling `OnPropertyChanged("ObservableServers")` won't do anything unless `ObservableServers` is defined as a `DependencyProperty`

Second of all, I don't see anywhere that you tried to recreate `ObservableServers`, so instantiating it inside the `get` is pretty pointless.

Which all come to this point:

For the bindings to work, you don't always have to **Notify** about the changes. If you don't, the XAML will just take the default value as its binding source. Therefore the backfield `_myListOfServersObjects` should be initialized by default:

```
private ObservableCollection<Server> _myListOfServersObjects = new ObservableCollection<Server>();
```

And the property should be like:

```
public ObservableCollection<Server> ObservableServers
{
    get
    {
        return _myListOfServersObjects;
    }
}
```

However, if you have a reason to monitor the changes made to the observable collection **itself** (not the items) you can define it as a `DependencyProperty` like:

```
public Server ObservableServers
{
    get { return (Server)GetValue(ObservableServersProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ObservableServersProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ObservableServersProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ObservableServers", typeof(Server), typeof(MainClass), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

### Edit

When binding to a property inside a parent view (e.g. The binding target is inside a UserControl, and the UserControl is inside a MainClass, and the MainClass has the property used as the binding source), you can use `RelativeSource` to find the binding source:

So instead of

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainClassTab, Path=ObservableServers}"
```

write

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainClass}, Path=ObservableServers}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @TwentyLokto does the method `AddItem` get executed?

Comment: @TwentyLokto and are you sure the rest of the bindings work? e.g. try adding a string to MainClass and binding it to a text box in the user control and see if the binding actually work

Comment: I add elements from MainClass without any problems, but I cannot add them from another class.

Comment: @TwentyLokto also there are some shady things going on in your sample files. why MainClass has an `InitializeComponent`? and why the UserControl tag in xaml looks nothing like proper xaml syntax?

Comment: @TwentyLokto you see this is exactly why I couldn't figure it out. because you posted three different codes! please pay more attention to the content of your question in order to get a faster result with less effort from our side

Comment: `AnotherClass` (or `MainClassTab` which is exactly the same) does not have the property you want to bind to. I will update my answer

Comment: @TwentyLokto please read the ASh's comment under your post in order to have a better experience in stackoverflow. thank you :)

Comment: Ehh.. not help.